# How to write cm-1(cm^-1) as unit in the axis label of gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Can anyone suggest me how to write cm-1(cm^-1) as unit in the axis label.

Thanks,

Biki

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can use the enhanced text mode, which is supported by many terminals, e.g.:

```
set terminal wxt enhanced
set xlabel 'cm^{-1}'
plot x
```

For some terminals (e.g. `epslatex`) you can of course also use `LaTeX` to typeset all text.